# Redirect users from www.mysite to mysite

Tags: redirect, https, no-www

We've been issued a new certificate for our website, but unfortunately without an alternative name for the www subdomain. Visiting the TLD without www works just fine.

Redirecting them via `.htaccess` doesn't work, probably because the initial connection isn't even made.

I've tried using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite/$1 [R]
```

Is there any way to "force" users away from www or do we need to be issued a new (fixed) certificate for our domain?

Answer (score 0):

Check this redirect (change example.com to your domain):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the redirect would follow after the SSL handshake (which fails because of the certificate).